# Install 16.04 LTS on new hardware with Dell Perc H740p raid controller

Tags: 16.04, drivers, dell, raid

I have read through all post I can find regarding the installation of 16.04 LTS on a Dell R640 server with a PERC H740 p controller. Everything I have found relates to adding the driver AFTER installing the kernel or during an upgrade from a previous build, not during a bare metal install on new hardware. The problem I am facing is that I can't write the boot image without installing the driver DURING the install as there are no drives mounted to write to. I have been able to install 17.10 LTS and upgrade it to 18.04 successfully. I need to build a 16.04 image for an application and can't locate the driver as a separate download to add during the build.

How do I ADD the driver DURING the install?

Comment: You would first have to find a driver for 16.04 and then probably modify the iso. It might be easier to run 16.04 in a VM such as kvm

Answer (score 0):

Dell R640 PERC H740P controller is supported in the 16.04 HWE installer. My error was searching for a separate HWE ISO image. I didn't realize that it is included in the 16.04.4 LTS server image as well. Reran the install from the HWE selection and viola there are my drives. Thanks go to Dr. Donald Kinghorn over at the Puget Systems site for pointing me in the right direction.